# Speeding up plotting of a network graph through sampling

Tags: r, graph, plot, sampling

I am trying to plot a network graph that has 3,296 edges and 2,893,873 ties. This is taking a long time. Is there any feasible way of speeding up the plotting of the graph through just sampling parts of it? Is there a way to randomly sample from a graph so as to receive a smaller, more manageable graph, but which still is "representative"?

Currently I am using the `igraph` package, but I would also be open to the `network` or `sna` packages.

Comment: Plotting networks is expensive! Try zooming in to an interesting part of the graph if you can.

Comment: That's a _huge_ graph. What layout algorithm are you using?

Comment: @hrbrmstr: I'm using Fruchterman Reingold. Do you think sampling from the graph might be a solution?

Comment: I think you have a few options. Determine salient communities and plot a high level graph without the nodes just communities. Then produce other, more detailed graphs at a next level down for each community, possibly doing graph-based node clustering for a more macro view. Then have another view of smaller clusters with all the detail level. Kinda of like a "small multiples" for graphs.